# Android DateFormat using specific format *and* respecting current user preferences

Tags: android, date, format

I have a time in millis and I need to display that to the user in a particular readable format, depending on the current device configuration:

```
java.text.DateFormat mDateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(this.getApplicationContext());
java.text.DateFormat mTimeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this.getApplicationContext());
```

I use `String mDateFormat.format(java.util.Date myFooDate)` to retrieve it.

However, it only returns "*31/12/2011*" (or *12/31/2011* depending on locale).

I wanted it to be "*Sun 31/12*" (or "*Sun 12/31*", automatically of course...).

Call me stupid, but I couldn't find the option (~ 1 hour into this)... I only found the option to hardcode the String format (using those "MM", "HH" and similars), but I as I said, I want it to respect current device preferences *in that particular format*. If the user uses month/date, I don't want to do differently.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Peter O. and dmon, I will check that later and return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you should inspect the value of `mDateFormat`.  If it's a [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you can cast `mDateFormat` to a SimpleDateFormat and call the `toPattern()` method.  Then check whether a capital M in the resulting string is followed by a lower-case D (not necessarily immediately) or vice versa.  This can help guide the specific format you use.

Here's the complete source code.  I place it in the public domain.

```
public static boolean isMonthBeforeDay(DateFormat df){
    if(df instanceof SimpleDateFormat){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=(SimpleDateFormat)df;
        String pattern=sdf.toPattern();
        int i=0;
        int dayFound=-1;
        int monthFound=-1;
        while(i<pattern.length()){
            if(pattern.charAt(i)=='\''){
                // Ignore quoted text
                i++;
                while(i<pattern.length()){
                    if(pattern.charAt(i)=='\''){
                        // Possible end of quoted text
                        if(i+1>=pattern.length())
                            break;
                        else if(pattern.charAt(i+1)=='\''){
                            i++;
                        } else {
                            i++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if(pattern.charAt(i)=='M' && monthFound<0){
                monthFound=i;
            }
            else if(pattern.charAt(i)=='d' && dayFound<0){
                dayFound=i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(monthFound>=0 && dayFound>=0){
            // Found both month and day in pattern
            return (monthFound<dayFound);
        }
        // Assume true, you can change to false if you want
        // the day to come before the month by default
        return true;
    } else {
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        FieldPosition fpMonth=new FieldPosition(DateFormat.MONTH_FIELD);
        FieldPosition fpDay=new FieldPosition(DateFormat.DATE_FIELD);
        GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar(2000,0,20);
        Date d=gc.getTime();
        // Find the field position of the month
        df.format(d,sb,fpMonth);
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        // Find the field position of the day
        df.format(d,sb,fpDay);
        return fpMonth.getBeginIndex()<fpDay.getBeginIndex();
    }
}
```

Comment: A catch-all solution is to feed a known unambiguous date & time through it and check if the month or day comes first in the output.

Comment: Accepted answer. You and dmon provided very good answers, and he even mentioned the need to remove the year part from the pattern. I didn't know how to work with the dateFormat (I knew how to work with patterns themselves...). The differential of your answer was that you clued me into looking at the values and casting to SimpleDateFormat, and I wasn't aware of that. From there I used toPattern and replaced the year pattern with the knowledge I already had. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the format you want (doesn't seem to be a common pattern either) from either of Android's `DateFormat` or `DateUtils` classes. I believe you're gonna have to assemble it yourself. If you always want your DAY_OF_WEEK to be in front, then it's trivial to take the date format string from the format object you get (call `toPattern()`), remove the year part (`/yyyy` or `yyyy/`), and concatenate it with the `EEE` to create the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Utility class for producing strings with formatted date/time.

This class takes as inputs a format string and a representation of a date/time. The format string controls how the output is generated.

Formatting characters may be repeated in order to get more detailed representations of that field. For instance, the format character 'M' is used to represent the month. Depending on how many times that character is repeated you get a different representation.

```
For the month of September:

M -> 9

MM -> 09

MMM -> Sep

MMMM -> September
```

The effects of the duplication vary depending on the nature of the field. See the notes on the individual field formatters for details. For purely numeric fields such as HOUR adding more copies of the designator will zero-pad the value to that number of characters.

```
For 7 minutes past the hour:

m -> 7

mm -> 07

mmm -> 007

mmmm -> 0007
```

And

```
Examples for April 6, 1970 at 3:23am:

"MM/dd/yy h:mmaa" -> "04/06/70 3:23am"

"MMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa" -> "Apr 6, 1970 3:23am"

"MMMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa" -> "April 6, 1970 3:23am"

"E, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa" -> "Mon, April 6, 1970 3:23am&

"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa" -> "Monday, April 6, 1970 3:23am"

"'Noteworthy day: 'M/d/yy" -> "Noteworthy day: 4/6/70"
```

Regards, [Mehul Patel](http://www.facebook.com/mehulp89)

Comment: Read the question again and you'll see that I'm not asking that, but thanks for your time.